# Multi threading webrequests?

Tags: vb.net

I'm programming a tool that'll go through a lot of websites and see if they contain a text that's in a textbox.
Now I wan't to add multi threading so it goes quite a lot faster, most preferably I'd dynamically add threads.
This is my code now but it didn't work because it says index ouf of range. And I doubt it work anyways.

```
Dim clsThreads As New Generic.List(Of System.Threading.Thread)
Dim numberOfthreads As Integer = 1
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For Each strLine1 As String In TextBox1.Text.Split({vbCr, vbLf}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        For Each strLine2 As String In TextBox2.Text.Split({vbCr, vbLf}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            clsThreads(numberOfthreads) = New Thread(Sub() Me.request(strLine1, strLine2))
            clsThreads(numberOfthreads).Name = "Thread: " + numberOfthreads.ToString
            clsThreads(numberOfthreads).IsBackground = True
            clsThreads(numberOfthreads).Start()

            numberOfthreads = numberOfthreads + 1
            If (numberOfthreads.Equals(20)) Then
                numberOfthreads = 0
            End If

        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

So, how do I implement multi threading in a smart way?

This is my request sub:

```
Public Sub request(ByVal username, ByVal mail)
    Dim req As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/" + username)
    req.Method = "GET"
    Dim res As WebResponse = req.GetResponse()
    Dim dataStream As Stream = res.GetResponseStream()
    Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
    Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
    If responseFromServer.Contains(mail) Then
        TextBox3.Text = TextBox3.Text + vbNewLine + username
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On
Option Infer Off
Public Class Form1
    Dim ActiveThreads As New List(Of System.Threading.Thread)
    Delegate Sub delRemoveThread(thread As Threading.Thread)
    Sub removeThread(thread As Threading.Thread)
        If Me.InvokeRequired Then
            Me.Invoke(New delRemoveThread(AddressOf removeThread), thread)
        Else
            ActiveThreads.Remove(thread)
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button1_Click3(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        For i As Integer = 1 To 20
            Dim th As New Threading.Thread(New Threading.ParameterizedThreadStart(Sub()
                                                                                      request("username", "mail")
                                                                                      removeThread(Threading.Thread.CurrentThread)
                                                                                  End Sub))
            th.Start()
        Next
    End Sub
    Public Sub request(ByVal username As String, ByVal mail As String)
        Dim req As Net.WebRequest = Net.WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/" + username)
        req.Method = "GET"
        Dim res As Net.WebResponse = req.GetResponse()
        Dim dataStream As IO.Stream = res.GetResponseStream()
        Dim reader As New IO.StreamReader(dataStream)
        Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
        If responseFromServer.Contains(mail) Then
            TextBox3.Text = TextBox3.Text + vbNewLine + username
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```